# Video Processing Library in dotnet core Desktop Application

Tags: c#, desktop-environment

is there any library in dotnet core which can help me in displaying the Live IP camera in my WPF Desktop Application. Furthermore, i also want to save the file in video format which is displayed in the Desktop Application. Library should be cross-platform.

**Technology:**

1. Avalonia UI (WPF)
2. Dotnet core 3.1

Comment: AvaloniaUI is a clone of WPF, but not real WPF. Compatible libraries can vary.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [OpenCVSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) which is one of the possible bindings for [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/)